# MySQL Database Relationships with Specific attributes

Tags: mysql, database-design, relationships

I'm creating a resorts database and backend.

This backend allows the admin to create new resorts and then specify which amenities are included in a resort.

Amenities can be : tennis court, pool, etc.

Sounds easy right? The problem I'm running into is each amenity needs an attribute:  [near by]  or  [on location].

The way I'm thinking of doing it is:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `amenity_resort_assn` (
  `amenities_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `resorts_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`amenities_id`,`resorts_id`),
  KEY `IDX_amenityresortassn_1` (`amenities_id`),
  KEY `IDX_amenityresortassn_2` (`resorts_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `resorts` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT ;


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `amenities` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `amenities_onsite_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `IDX_amenities_1` (`amenities_onsite_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT ;


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `onsite_type` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `IDX_amenitiesonsitetype_1` (`name`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT;
```

Comment: Why reference the amenity by whether they are on site or not?  I think it would make more sense to place *is_nearby* and *is_onsite* boolean columns in your `amenity_resort_assn` table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right to leave open the possibility of having some different onsite attribute besides "on location" and "near by".  Maybe you add "within 20 miles" or "in your room" later.

So I suggest doing the tables this way:

```
RESORTS: id, name
AMENITIES: id, name
ONSITE_TYPE: id, name
AMENITY_RESORT_ASSN: id, resorts_id, amenities_id, onsite_type_id
```

This seems to be how the relationship of these things works in real life--each of these characteristics is independent of the others.  And this leaves the possibility that a resort has both a restaurant on site and a restaurant near by.

Comment: Thank you sir, that is EXACTLY what I tried to explain. I commented it out though with < ! --   , didn't  realize this forum would actually comment it out like HTML would.   I LOVE IT! I'm still open to other alternative but this seems to be the right approach. ;)